# Stripe y google endpoints

Tags: java, rest, google-app-engine, endpoint, stripe

Tengo un webhook en Stripe que se conecta a un endpoint mandando un Json en el body, sin embargo no estoy muy seguro de como obtener ese json usando los endpoints de google, ya que tengo entendido que solo maneja pojos, estoy intentando con lo siguiente :

```
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.stripe.model.Event;
import com.yogome.heroesofknowledge.rest.pojos.GenericResponse;
import com.yogome.heroesofknowledge.rest.pojos.Response;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


@Api(name = "eventos")
public class EventosEndpoint {

@ApiMethod(name = "guardar", httpMethod = "POST")
public Response guardar(Event event) {

    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName());

    logger.log(Level.INFO, event.getType());

    return new GenericResponse(event.getType());
    }

}
```

Pero efectivamente me manda el siguiente error:

> > com.google.api.server.spi.SystemService invokeServiceMethod: exception occurred while calling backend method (SystemService.java:378)
> >     com.google.api.server.spi.response.BadRequestException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.stripe.model.StripeObject, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information

por lo cual necesito una forma de poder ya sea obtener el json en bruto o castear el objeto event.

Answer (score 0):

Para que el endpoint pueda parsear el json que envía stripe, el objeto debería cumplir con 2 condciones:

1. Tener un constructor vacio
2. Que todos los campos que se quieren parsear tengan un getter publico o sean ellos públicos.

Lo más seguro es que este objeto de Stripe no cumple con las condiciones. Mi recomendación sería que hagas un objeto propio que intercepte la llamada y construyas el objeto de Stripe a mano.